# Trigger to update table after insert to insert or update into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am having a little trouble with my after insert trigger it does not update/insert into the table and I am not sure why.

I have the tables employee, position, certification, employeecertification, positioncertification.

What I need to do is after a Position is assigned a Certification then all employees that are defined in that position (Employee:PositionId = Ins.PositionId] need to get the certification added (if it does not already exist in their record) , I might need to update them where they do exist (but for the moment do not believe that will be a requirement).

I have been getting a couple different results (neither is correct)

*1: EmployeeId can not insert null into EmployeeId*

*2: On some other test data - nothing is inserted.*

I have the following trigger with the sql for creation of tables that follows:

**The Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_InsNew_PositionCertification]
ON [dbo].[PositionCertification]
AFTER INSERT
AS
Insert into EmployeeCertification
(CertificationId, EmployeeId)
Select Ins.CertificationId, Emp.EmployeeId
From inserted Ins
Left Join dbo.Employee Emp On Emp.PositionId = Ins.PositionId
Left Join dbo.Certification Trw On Trw.CertificationId = Ins.CertificationId

WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT EmployeeId, CertificationId 
FROM 
EmployeeCertification 
WHERE EmployeeId = Emp.EmployeeId AND CertificationId = Ins.CertificationId);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PositionCertification] ENABLE TRIGGER [trig_InsNew_PositionCertification]
GO
```

**CREATE TABLES:**

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Position](
        [PositionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Position] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [PositionId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
        [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [EmployeeName] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
        [PositionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [EmployeeId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Position] FOREIGN KEY([PositionId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Position] ([PositionId])
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Position] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Position]
    GO
    
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Certification](
        [CertificationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Certification] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CertificationId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    
    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeCertification](
        [EmployeeCertificationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [CertificationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    
     CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeCertification] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [EmployeeId] ASC,
        [CertificationId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeCertification]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpCertification_Certification] FOREIGN KEY([CertificationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Certification] ([CertificationId])
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeCertification] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpCertification_Certification]
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeCertification]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpCertification_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeId])
    GO
    
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeCertification] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpCertification_Employee]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PositionCertification](
    [PositionCertificationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PositionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CertificationId] [int] NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_PositionCertification] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PositionId] ASC,
    [CertificationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: _I might need to update them..._ Don't add requirements about functionality you **might** need to implement in the future. That will only add confusion and distract from the current goal. And it seems you left out DDL for the most important table - the one you created a trigger for. And a simple suggestion. Remove the clutter from your DDL. Hand write it so it is compact and easy to read without the complications of using SSMS to script. Better yet, create a complete script that includes sample data and the test inserts that resulted in the claimed errors.

Comment: Your outer join in the trigger is obviously a part of the problem.

Comment: @SMor I added the table .. I will try to get to sqlFiddle and post it with data ,  I guess I should be doing an inner join instead of left join .. that is probably the whole issue.

Comment: @SMor I changed the code to inner join , and it works as expected . If you desire to put that in answer - I will mark it as answer - since you mentioned the outer join in your comment.